# xPages Extension Library dialog control

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I hope all is well. I am new to extension library and want to use dialog control along with others features. Can anybody share step by step guide for extension library. I am using IBM Notes 9.0.1.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the demo database in the OpenNTF download for samples. For walkthrough code and explanations, look at [XPages Extension Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00RLZNOOQ)

Comment: no demo database found on OpenNTF, i think i have to go with the book mentioned in above link.

Comment: The demo database is in the XPages Extension Library download on OpenNTF, https://extlib.openntf.org/. I would strongly recommend using the latest release from OpenNTF rather than the core 9.0.1 release. The OpenNTF version includes over three years of enhancements, including Bootstrap, enhancements to Value Picker and Name Picker.

Comment: thanks - but for latest release I also have to do some updates on my client and server side?

Comment: The demo database should still work on core 9.0.1, as far as I'm aware. If not, use the version from the last 9.0.0 OpenNTF ExtLib release. That will be the version that was used for 9.01 core release.